# The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.DataFactory' error

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-data-factory

Going through [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-get-started-using-vs/) "Create a pipeline with Copy Activity using Visual Studio"
and receiving this error when I hit publish.

> Creating datafactory-Name:VSTutorialFactory,Tags:,Subscription:Pay-As-You-Go,ResourceGroup:MyAppGroup,Location:North Europe,
>
> 24/03/2016 11:30:34- Error creating data factory:
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudException: MissingSubscriptionRegistration:
> The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.DataFactory'.

The error is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In Azure, for each functionality there's a resource provider (Microsoft.DataFactory for example).

By default, your Azure Subscription is not registered with all resource providers and because your Subscription is not registered with `Microsoft.DataFactory` resource provider, you're getting this error.

What you have to do is manually register your subscription with a resource provider. If you're using Azure PowerShell, you can use `Register-AzureRmResourceProvider` Cmdlet to achieve the same. You would need to use syntax like below:

```
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.DataFactory
```

Once your Subscription is registered with this resource provider, this error will go away.

Comment: @Schneider believe so. If my memory serves me right, you would need to click on "Subscriptions" and then "Resource Providers".

Comment: @Schneider Yes, this can be done via "cloud shell" besides search text box on the header.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm wondering why we're required to register it manually. Are there any reasons and does doing so have any side effects?

Comment: If others are getting this error for a different resource, then you can find the resource that you need to use in lieu of "Microsoft.DataFactory" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-services-resource-providers

Comment: It would make sense to me that if a customer tries to create a resource that is not registered by default that Azure would automate that part of the process. 

If you dangle an enabled button or link in front of a user in the portal then it's a bad experience to be immediately met with an error and little explanation on how to fix it. 

Auto register, or disable the link with an explanation on how to enable it.

Comment: The modern version is obiously: `Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace`.

Answer (score 119):

You can also register resource providers under your subscription in the portal

[image]

Comment: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade

Answer (score 53):

The instructions here worked for me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-register-provider-errors#solution-3---azure-portal

From the portal, select All services.

[image]

Select Subscriptions.

[image]

From the list of subscriptions, select the subscription you want to use for registering the resource provider.

[image]
For your subscription, select Resource providers.

[image]

Look at the list of resource providers, and if necessary, select the Register link to register the resource provider of the type you're trying to deploy.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

To achieve the same thing with the azure cli you just need to set

```
azure provider register Microsoft.DataFactory
```

In order for this to work you need to be executing under the arm config mode

```
azure config mode arm
```

and you need to make sure you have selected the appropriate account/subscription for this to be executed against

```
azure account list
azure account set <SubscriptionNameOrId>
```

Comment: For CLI 2.0 on Mac: `az provider register -n Microsoft.DataFactory`

Comment: Your instructions are backwards. You tell people to register it, then you tell them to check it has the right account.

Answer (score 11):

You can use also az command-line tool

- To register

```
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.DataFactory
```

- Notes

Execute both commands before to log in and switch to the desired subscription

```
az login
az account set --subscription <name or id>
```

Comment: Apparently registering takes a while. You can follow the status, using `az provider show -n Microsoft.DataFactory`

Answer (score 8):

**My objective:**

I wanted to create an *auto shutdown* schedule for my *virtual machine* in *my Azure portal*. Then I received the following error message:`Schedule failed to update {"error":{"code":"MissingSubscriptionRegistration","message":"The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.DevTestLab'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to register subscriptions.","details":[{"code":"MissingSubscriptionRegistration","target":"Microsoft.DevTestLab","message":"The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.DevTestLab'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to register subscriptions."}]}}`

**What is the error message saying?**

It is saying `The subscription is not registered to use namespace '**Microsoft.DevTestLab**`

**How do I register that namespace?**

1. Click on the "Subscription" tab on Azure portal
2. Select "Resource providers"
3. Type the namespace you want to register in the search box
4. click on the Register button
5. It will take about 5 minutes to finish the registration and all set to go.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Step 1.

```
az account list
```

Step 2.

```
az account set --subscription "Pago por uso"
```

Step 3.

```
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.DataFactory
```

Registering is still on-going. You can monitor using `az provider show -n Microsoft.DataFactory`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with exception:

```
Hyak.Common.CloudExceptionMissingSubscriptionRegistration: The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.DataFactory'.
```

I think this is a little bug in the way how Data Factory Provider is registered for subscription.

I fixed that by creating first **Data Factory manually** and then I was able to create next one automatically using:

```
DataFactoryManagementClient
```

Hopefully, it will be helpful for others working with Azure Data Factories.

Answer (score 0):

User PowerShell core and AZ 3.3.0 for me it worked:

Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network