# Azure Keyvault CLI error: The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.KeyVault'

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I get the error below when creating a new KeyVault

```
The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.KeyVault'
```

For all other products, the solution is to deploy a similar resource in the same region/account using the GUI, however KeyVault isn't available in the portal yet. (classic or preview)

I followed the instructions to [create a KeyVault are here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-manage-with-cli/).  I just happen to be on OSX if that matters, but NPM works on all platforms.

```
Chris$ sudo npm install azure-cli -g
Chris$ echo '. <(azure --completion)' >> .zshrc
Chris$ echo 'source ~/azure.completion.sh' >> ~/.bash_profile


Chris$ azure login -u chris@here.com
Chris$ azure telemetry --enable
Chris$ azure config mode arm
Chris$ azure location list
Chris$ azure group create 'agent77keysRM' 'centralus'
Chris$ azure account list
Chris$ azure account set "AccountDisplayName"


Chris$ azure keyvault create --vault-name "agent77keys" --resource-group 'agent77keysRM' --location 'centralus'
info:    Executing command keyvault create
+ Checking pre-condition                                                       
+ Creating vault agent77keys                                                    
error:   The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.KeyVault'.
error:   Error information has been recorded to /Users/Chris/.azure/azure.err
error:   keyvault create command failed
```

I'm not dumping the azure.err here, for privacy reasons, but the key info is:

```
   'x-ms-client-request-id': 'b9991d6f-bd8c-4e62-b887-cac9b90d0281',
    'accept-language': 'en-US',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'user-agent': 'WindowsAzureXplatCLI/0.10.2' 
    ...
    'x-ms-failure-cause': 'gateway',
    'x-ms-request-id': 'fcb04d40-306f-40bd-b8df-f1b42b283010',
    'x-ms-correlation-request-id': 'fcb04d40-306f-40bd-b8df-f1b42b283010',
    'x-ms-routing-request-id': 'EASTUS:20160806T013209Z:fcb04d40-306f-40bd-b8df-f1b42b283010',
```

Looks like registering fixed it, here is the output if someone wants to see that it tells you HSM keys aren't created... easy fix, just add the SKU

```
info:    Executing command keyvault create
+ Checking pre-condition                                                       
+ Creating vault xxxxx                                                    
info:    Created vault xxxxx
data:    id "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxxxxxs"
data:    name "xxxx"
data:    type "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"
data:    location "centralus"
data:    properties sku family "A"
data:    properties sku name "Standard"
data:    properties tenantId "xxxx"
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 tenantId "xxxx
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 objectId "xxxx
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 permissions keys 0 "get"
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 permissions keys 1 "create"
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 permissions keys 2 "delete"
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 permissions keys 3 "list"
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 permissions keys 4 "update"
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 permissions keys 5 "import"
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 permissions keys 6 "backup"
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 permissions keys 7 "restore"
data:    properties accessPolicies 0 permissions secrets 0 "all"
data:    properties enabledForDeployment false
data:    properties vaultUri "https://xxxxx.vault.azure.net"
warn:    This vault does not support HSM-protected keys. Please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=512521 for the vault service tiers.
warn:    When creating a vault, specify the --sku parameter to select a service tier that supports HSM-protected keys.
info:    keyvault create command OK
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see this thread as to why you're getting this error: [The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.DataFactory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200143/the-subscription-is-not-registered-to-use-namespace-microsoft-datafactory-error).

To fix this issue, you would need to register your subscription with `Microsoft.KeyVault` resource provider. You can do the same by using the following command:

```
azure provider register --namespace "Microsoft.KeyVault"
```

With Azure Resource Manager

```
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace 'Microsoft.KeyVault'
```

Comment: The command in the Az module is `Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.KeyVault`. Details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#azure-powershell